# Energy delivered to unstable limit cycle

Tags: energy, oscillators, complex-systems, bifurcation

For a given family of stable and unstable $T$-periodic limit cycles $\Gamma$ forming a manifold $\mathcal{M}\subset \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^p$ of some (nonconservative) $p$-parametric $n$-dimensional system we can compute (lost, delivered, ...) energy over a period $T$  for each of the cycle $\Gamma(\mathbf{\mu})\in\mathcal{M}$, $\mathbf{\mu}\in\mathbb{R}^p$.

My question is, what is the meaning of the energy for unstable limit cycles? For stable limit cycles it is clear, but if I look at the unstabe ones as to limit cycles which are reached in time-reversal, how should I interpret energy of such limit cycles?

Especially consider some fold limit cycles in system with hysteresis, where we have one stable $\Gamma$ and one unstable $\Gamma$ for a single value $\mu$. What is the interpretation of energy of the unstable cycle then?

Comment: I'd think that even if we use a definition for unstable cycles based on time reversal, it's still just a cycle in forward time and the interpretation would be the same as for the stable ones.

Comment: If I have one stable and one unstable, it is reasonable to compute energy in the system only for stable which is physically observable. But your argument suggests that I can add energy for the unstable cycle as well. But its not correct because we would measure only the energy delivered to the stable cycle, right?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes — for typical initial conditions or phase-space average, only stable cycles should show up.

Comment: So what is the energy of the unstable limit cycle coexisting with stable one?

Comment: What's its value? It'll depend on the cycle. And it's a state of the system only reachable from a zero-measure set of initial conditions.